# Can't load first OS(Seven) on primary partition while system loads second OS(XP) on a logical partition

Tags: boot, operating-systems

Excuse me for the long title that I've chosen. I made a logical partition for installing another OS which it was XP but, I forgot to change it to a primary one and after that my first OS which is a Seven would never load up. I installed **Paragon Partition Manager** on XP and it has a **Boot Manager** program which it can show a list of installed operating systems to select when the system is powered on after post screen. In that list there is just Seven and no XP. Right now I'm using the **Paragon Boot Manager** program to load my first OS. I know that I made mistake and now the first boot-able sector is became to the XP partition. What can I do now to correct this problem?

Sorry if it's not clear to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is done automatically with [Dual-boot Repair tool](http://boyans.net/DualBootRepair.html)

Run tool and click on "Automatic Repair". This will put Windows 7 as default boot OS.

To add XP as dual boot choice use Visual BCD Editor - "Create missing Windows loaders" from popup menu. Again automaic action - no parameters to specify.

**General rule:**
To be able to boot a Windows OS must put its boot related files on active primary partition, root folder.

For XP the files are - ntldr, ntdetect.com and boot.ini

For Windows 7 - bootmgr, and \boot folder (with BCD store inside)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Really didn't know what to do! I'll try this way and I think it's gonna work :)